# MVC6 Validation-For attribute not working properly?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

In my project, I'm feeding my views a view model that has a property `Company` of the type `Company`. The company class has multiple fields with different validation requirements, and they all have data annotations.

When I submit my form, the controller will flag the modelstate as invalid and pass the error messages back to my view, and they are displayed under the summary. However, they are not displayed under their respective field.

Here is an example snippet of my code:

```
<div asp-validation-summary="ValidationSummary.All" class="text-danger"></div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input asp-for="Company.Name" class="form-control" placeholder="Company Name" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Company.Name" class="text-danger" />
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
}
```

The errors never populate before the form submission, and they do not show under their respective fields. Instead, I only see them under the summary.

I do have a javascript error popping up in chrome stating something along the lines of: `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'unobtrusive' of undefined`

But I'm fairly stumped here.

Comment: Hi. Can You Post Your script render section and bundle config ?

Comment: I added my scripts section, but I'm not quite sure about my bundle config (if there is one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For client side validation in ASP.NET 5 - MVC6 add:

```
@section Scripts {
   @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }
}
```

Then add the following in `Views/Shared/_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml`

```
<environment names="Development">
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
</environment>
<environment names="Staging,Production">
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"
        asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"
        asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.validator">
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/5.2.3/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"
        asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"
        asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.validator && window.jQuery.validator.unobtrusive">
</script>
</environment>
```

Create a standard ASP.NET 5 Web Application in Visual Studio and see how its implemented.